# Express.js: real time user comment replies - Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, comments

I want to create a commenting system for my website and users should be able to reply to each others' comments. Is this possible with express.js? Something like this:

```
app.post('/reply', function(req, res){
  User.findOne({'_id':req.body.userId}, function(err, user){ // I get this from the client when he clicks the reply button
    user.send({'message': req.body.message, 'from': req.user.username}); // is this possible ?
    res.end();
  }
});
```

I could do it with socket.io, but that would require me to save all the socket ids when someone visits another page (isn't that too cpu intensive and a bad practice?)

Is there another way to do it? Maybe with another module? Thank you!

Comment: If you're worried that there are too many people active at the same time, you could always go with long polling (regular ajax calls to the server, e.g. every 2 seconds).

Comment: Ok, but can the `user.send()` part, work? And if it can, how would the client code be like? (I mean the code that "listens" to the send function)

Comment: With your code, you would only send it back to the user that hit `reply`. I mean, you probably have a database or some other form of storage in the background?

Comment: I do have a database, but the `req.body.userId` belongs to the user with the initial comment, if I had to get the id of the user who made the reply I'd  use `req.user._id`!

Comment: So, is this code possible, and if it is, how does the client listen to data being sent by the server?